# Appending array in swift values mixed up

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to get data from a Firestore Database which looks like:

```
texts - 1 - message (String)
            author (String)
      - 2 - message (String)
            author (String)
      ...
```

For testing purposes the data I am setting the message String to be is "test" + the number that they are contained in (eg 1 would be test1)

The code I am using to display these in a stack view as labels is:

```
if startNumOfMessages > 0 {
    let g = DispatchGroup()
    for message in stride(from: startNumOfMessages, through: 1, by: -1) {
        g.enter()
        print(message)
        db.collection("chats").document(self.userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup")!).collection("texts").document("\(message)").getDocument { (doc, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("Error getting message \(message)")
            }
            else{
                if doc!.exists{
                    let messData = doc!.data()
                    messageArray.append(messData!["message"] as! String)
                    authorArray.append(messData!["author"] as! String)
                }
                else{
                    print("Document Doesnt exist")
                }
            }
            g.leave()
        }
    }
    //Display them
    g.notify(queue: .main){
        print(messageArray)
        for num in stride(from: messageArray.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1){
            let authorLabel = UILabel()
            authorLabel.text = authorArray[num]
            authorLabel.font = UIFont(name:"SF Pro", size: 10.0)
            authorLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(authorLabel)
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = messageArray[num]
            self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

However when I `print(messageArray)` the array comes out as

```
["test1", "test3", "test2", "test4", "test5"]
```

So my question is why does this happen? I have tried messing about with the loops but they seem fine and I have checked the data that it is getting and there is nothing incorrect there.

Comment: If you print the messages in `getDocument`'s closure where you are appending them in the array, are they in correct order? Documentation to [Order and limit data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) says: ***By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID***, and you need to use `order(by:`, to actually sort the data.

Comment: They aren't in the correct order that is what is confusing me, it is in the same order as the final array, does this mean anything?

Comment: However they do come in the same messed up order every time

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is no guarantee that the getDocument completion closures will be called in the same order as the order you call getDocument. E.g. one may come from local cache, other from network so may get reordered.

Comment: Thats a good thought I will look into that, it links to what Swapnil said

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 2:

Sorry, you don't need `order(by:`.

I checked the code in your question again, and everything i have written in my answer seems to be irrelevant. Since you are retrieving from **texts** collection using `document("\(message)")`, where `message` is ctually the count, the only explainatin is your data must be incorrect. i.e. you must have set ***test3*** in object numbered **2**, and vice versa.

An easy way to verify this is to add following print statement before / after the code to append text to your `messageArray`:

```
if let messageString = messData?["message"] as? String {
    print("text #: \(message) - message: \(messageString)")
}
```

---

Old answer (kept here just for reference)

As mentioned in my comment in [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) it is clearly mentioned :

> By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID. You can specify the sort order for your data using orderBy()

Meaning, the sort torder you expect for your data (by messsage text, or order in which you entered the data), is not default / guaranteed.

Just use `.order(by: "message")` to get the data in you required order.

EDIT:

You needto apply sort on a collection.
So, instead of:

```
.collection("texts")
```

you need to do use:

```
.collection("texts").order(by: "message")
```

Comment: How do I get the data from there though as `doc!.data()` doesnt exist and I can't find a function to get the data

Comment: I added the sort onto the collection but I cannot get the data, the point of the question was to get the data correctly

Comment: were you able to get the data before sort (even in wrong order)? nothing has to change just because of  `order(by:`.

Comment: The order by overrides the command after that so I cannot do collection.order.getDocument

Comment: Can you share the code you use to set the data?

Comment: Or the raw json object whihc you set

Comment: No json was used, and for the purpose of testing this I set the data directly in firebase

Comment: Ok, i might have not read your code corectly. Please check my updated answer above.